# Animate Content Within a DIV

Tags: jquery, animation

Alright, this is a bit hard to explain, and therefore a bit hard to search for, so please forgive me if it's been asked before. I'll be thorough in my explanation.

I have a web page with a varying number of icons. When the user clicks on an icon, it should show the content related to that icon within a `DIV`. Here's where it gets tricky. No matter which icon a user clicks, the content should load in to the same `DIV`. However, only content for one icon should be visible at a time. So if the content for "A" is loaded, and the user clicks on "B", the content for "A" should fade out and be replaced with content "B" fading in, same thing with "C," "D," etc. (probably up to a maximum of about 5). The content can vary widely in size, so the containing `DIV` for the content needs to animate its height to adjust to the current content.

Where I'm stuck is the animation. I've figured out how to hide and show different content basically by setting `display: none;`" and `display: block;` on the different content sections based on where the user clicks, but I can't figure out how to get any kind of animation going.

I'm open to using a pre-made script, but remember that icons and content area are in separate wrappers, so a normal jQuery tab script or accordion script isn't going to work.

Here's my scirpt so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".heading").click(function(event) {       
        // remove active class from previous, add to current
        $(".hidden.active").removeClass("active");
        $(".hidden." + activeContent).addClass("active");       
    }); 
});
```

CSS for `.hidden` and `.active`:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.hidden.active{
    display: block !important;
}
```

Anything can be modified if necessary, but not the fact that they're in separate wrappers.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the HTML aswell, or even better, create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you have with the show / hide stuff for us to play with !

Comment: Do you want the two things to be visible at the same time - that is, the fadeIn happens simultaneously with the fadeOut?  Another option - the fadeOut happens when you initiate the request for the new content and the fadeIn begins once the response comes back.  Either way, to get the overlapping efect, you want the wrapper to have position:relative and the inside content pieces to have position: absolute; top:0;left:0;

Comment: Have a look at `addClass` and `removeClass` from jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/

Comment: What is `activeContent`. The new content to show?

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think that is what the question is... The problem lies in animating to the new content in a dynamic fashion, not something statically defined in css to switch to.

Comment: @sg3s: The properties defined in the CSS will be animated though, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BsrJy/1/); is something like this what you are looking to do?

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="content-1" class="content-container">...</div>
    <div id="content-2" class="content-container">...</div>
    <div id="content-3" class="content-container">...</div>
</dvi>

<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" data-target="content-1">Content 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-target="content-2">Content 2</a>
    <a href="#" data-target="content-3">Content 3</a>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Hide all but First Content Container //
$('.content-container').hide().first().show();

// Bind to Button click Event //
$('#buttons a').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Set New Target from Button data-target Attribute //
    var $target = $('#'+$(this).data('target'));

    // Fade Out :visible Content and Fade In Target Content //
    $('.content-container').filter(':visible').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $target.fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

You could also replace [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) with [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) respectively to achieve different animation effects.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Only thing is, is there  way to hide all content initially, and then show content for the one a user clicks on? I've been trying to modify it for about an hour and haven't been able to figure it out. (I can almost get it, but it jumps to the new content, then fades that content out and back in, really odd).

Comment: @Rev Can you post your working code to jsfiddle.net and I can take a look to see what's going on.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/revxx14/6kRjw/6/ (CSS doesn't matter, I just can't stand unstyled text lol)

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow:hidden`, otherwise the `div` will snap to accommodate the new contents width/height, before you get a chance to do animation.

Comment: This seems like a plausible answer but in fact you don't know, so this is a guess, not an answer, until the question is clarified/supplemented with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/huckepick/XtuX2/

It's not very fancy yet. But it is simple, easy to understand and easy to extend.

UPDATE: [Added support for animated size change](http://jsfiddle.net/huckepick/XtuX2/2/)

```js
$('#menu button').click(function() {
  var identifier = $(this).attr("data-content-reference");
  var newContent = $("#content-" + identifier).html();
  $('#display').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $("#display").html(newContent);
    $('#display').animate({
      opacity: 1,
      height: 'toggle'
    }, 300, function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <button data-content-reference="a">A</button>
  <button data-content-reference="b">B</button>
  <button data-content-reference="c">C</button>
  <button data-content-reference="d">D</button>
  <button data-content-reference="e">E</button>
  <button data-content-reference="f">F</button>
</div>
<div id="display">
  content goes here!
</div>

<div class="hidden-content" id="content-a">some content from A</div>
<div class="hidden-content" id="content-b">some content from B
  <br/>new line</div>
<div class="hidden-content" id="content-c">some content from C
  <br/>new line
  <br/>new line</div>
<div class="hidden-content" id="content-d">some content from D
  <br/>new line
  <br/>new line
  <br/>another one</div>
<div class="hidden-content" id="content-e">some content from E</div>
<div class="hidden-content" id="content-f">some content from F</div>
```

Comment: I think the question was to animate the boundries of the content div to the new boundries needed to accommodate the new content (rather than resetting each time new content is loaded), but close :)

Comment: well, if the div is placed within a certain HTML environment, the environment changes with the div, isnt that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I've misunderstood (a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), as adeneo mentioned above, would be very helpful), but it seems like you just need to call [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) with a call to [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) as the callback, along the lines of:

```js
// try it out on http://jsfiddle.net/XyUps/1/

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(".active").fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).siblings("div").addClass("active").fadeIn();
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
    });
});
```

Here, the second argument in `fadeOut()` is the callback, a function to run when the animation has completed: this is a good way of making animations sequential in jQuery (just putting them on subsequent lines would run them simultaneously, which is probably not what you want).

Once you've mastered the basic principle, you could animate more/different properties in the same way using the [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function (`fadeOut` is short-hand for `animate({display: 'none'})` *etc.*).

Comment: sg3s, thanks for the assistance, but it was a deliberate choice to mention jsfiddle twice, and to link to the "add new fiddle" page rather than my solution.